# How do I create random hex digits without spaces?

Tags: text-processing, openssl

If I do something like:

```
openssl rand 16 > file.txt
```

I get a file that looks like this:

```
3e1c 37e2 96fc 7029 970c cc87 98fe 40f7
7c70 5a9a 30da 7b72 0064 9a54 ae9c ed91
```

Is there a way to do this without the spaces an newline characters?

Comment: You've got a weird version of `openssl` if that's the output you get. That is not the normal output.

Comment: for ex. `openssl rand 16 -hex` gave me `716e2480fa82103b5b2e1ea52d12e03c` . No spaces

Comment: Also see: [How to get a random string of 32 hexadecimal digits through command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34328759/how-to-get-a-random-string-of-32-hexadecimal-digits-through-command-line/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `tr` to delete the spaces and newlines like:

```
openssl rand 16 | tr -d '\n '  > file.txt
```

Or if your are really bad a remembering flags, you can use `tr` to convert the newlines to spaces, and then use `sed` to strip the spaces.

```
openssl rand 16 | tr '\n' ' ' | sed 's/ //g' > file.txt
```

Comment: Why use sed instead of `tr -d`?

Comment: @Gilles, because I am terrible at remembering flags....  Thanks for the heads up...

Answer (score 1):

`openssl rand 16` doesn't produce hexadecimal output, and `openssl rand -hex 16` doesn't output whitespace, and it outputs 16 bytes (32 hex digits), not 32 bytes (64 digits). But anyway, if you want to remove spaces and newlines, you can use `tr`:

```
$ cat data
3e1c 37e2 96fc 7029 970c cc87 98fe 40f7
7c70 5a9a 30da 7b72 0064 9a54 ae9c ed91
$ cat data | tr -d '\n '; echo
3e1c37e296fc7029970ccc8798fe40f77c705a9a30da7b7200649a54ae9ced91
```

To remove all characters that aren't hexadecimal digits, you can use `tr -dc 0-9A-Fa-f` or `tr -dc '[:xdigit:]'`.

If you want to produce random hexadecimal digits, you can get them from `/dev/urandom` (on Linux, might be `/dev/random` or `/dev/arandom` on other unix variants).

```
</dev/urandom od -An -tx1 | head -c 32 | tr -d ' \n'
```